# Scanner ignora una entrada

Tags: java, poo

estoy haciendo una prueba de POO en Java y por alguna razon el Scanner no me deja ingresar un dato.

```
package pkg1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class producto {
double precio;
String nombre;
String marca;
int cantidad;

public producto (){
    precio = 0.0;
    nombre = null;
    marca = null;
    cantidad = 0;
}
public producto (double precio,String nombre){
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public producto (double precio,String nombre,String marca,int cantidad){
    this.precio = precio;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.marca = marca;
    this.cantidad = cantidad;
}
public static void main (String ...s){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    producto pro1 = new producto (23.0,"chocolate");
    producto pro2 = new producto (0.0,null,null,0);
    System.out.println("el producto es " + pro1.nombre +" "+ pro1.precio);

    System.out.println("Ingrege el nombre del producto: ");
    pro2.nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrege el precio del producto: ");
    pro2.precio = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Ingrege la marca del producto: ");
    pro2.marca = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrege la cantidad del producto: ");
    pro2.cantidad = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Producto 2 \nNombre: "+pro2.nombre+"\nPrecio: "+pro2.precio
    + "\nMarca: "+pro2.marca+ "\nCantidad: "+pro2.cantidad
    );
}
}
```

Al correr el codigo y empezar a ingresar los datos, pasa esto:
[image: Se salta el campo para ingresar la marca y pasa al siguiente campo]

¿como puedo arreglar esto?

Comment: Creándote otro Scanner solo para entrada de datos numéricos y el que tienes usarlo solo para String.
Saludos

Answer (score -1):

Scanner tiene varios métodos para la lectura de datos, y sea cual sea el método que utilices siempre leerá una línea entera, así que siempre se utiliza Scanner.nextLine() y por tanto de primeras trata todo como si fuera String.

La clase String consta de un array de caracteres y cualquier cadena almacena un carácter de fin de línea '\0'.

Cuando escribes por ejemplo "Hola" y pulsas intro, en realidad almacenas {'H', 'o', 'l', 'a', '\0'}. Si ahora utilizas nextLine() no hay problema, tomas todos los caracteres.

Si escribes 45, aunque utilices nextInt() o nextDouble(), de primeras Scanner toma {'4', '5', '\0'}.

Qué pasa, que intentan convertir los datos a números así que toma el '4' y el '5' y lo transformar a 45, como número, y con eso el método ya ha terminado. Pero la cadena inicial contiene más datos. Falta el carácter '\0'. Si hay otra operación que necesita lectura por teclado, el carácter sigue formando parte del buffer de entrada y eso es lo que te está interpretando Scanner.nextLine() cuando pides la marca del producto.

Por tanto la solución es limpiar el buffer tras la conversión de números con nextLine().

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    producto pro1 = new producto(23.0, "chocolate");
    producto pro2 = new producto(0.0, null, null, 0);
    System.out.println("el producto es " + pro1.nombre + " " + pro1.precio);

    System.out.println("Ingrege el nombre del producto: ");
    pro2.nombre = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrege el precio del producto: ");
    pro2.precio = sc.nextDouble();
    sc.nextLine(); // Limpiamos el buffer
    System.out.println("Ingrege la marca del producto: ");
    pro2.marca = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingrege la cantidad del producto: ");
    pro2.cantidad = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Producto 2 \nNombre: " + pro2.nombre + "\nPrecio: " + pro2.precio
            + "\nMarca: " + pro2.marca + "\nCantidad: " + pro2.cantidad
    );
}
```